# How to jump only in currently open file?

Tags: cursor-movement, jumplist

Quite often, when using `CTRL-O` to jump back to an older position, vim takes me to other files I've been editing previously. Is there a command, to go back within the jumplist **just in the current file**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is command that is close to what you need: `g;` will bring you back to *older change position*, `g,` will go forward to *newer change position* .

List of change position can be displayed with `:changes`.

Answer (score 7):

My [EnhancedJumps plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2695) offers separate special mappings that restrict the jump targets to only local locations (in the same buffer) and remote locations (only in other buffers).

Comment: Your answer is probably the correct one to my question, but tivn's answer feels more like the vim-way of accomplishing what I need to do. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, backtick-backtick:

```
``
```

goes back to the previous mark (but *only* the previous mark) in the current buffer.